# SpriteKit game deployed from TestFlight may not display correct on iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, testflight

I’m having an issue with games I’ve been developing for iOS using SpriteKit

The issue deals with when the games are deployed through TestFlight and installed on iPhone devices.
On some phones the games will not display correctly. They will appear zoomed in from the center and be clipped at the edges.

Here is a screen shot (taken from an iPhone 6) of what one of the games is supposed to look like:

[image]
￼

Here is what the game can look like when it is clipped (screen shot taken from an iPhone X):

￼[image]

I have three iPhone devices I’ve been using for testing:
iPhone 5 running iOS 10.3.3
iPhone 6 running iOS 11.2.1
iPhone 8 running iOS 11.2.1

On all three of these devices the game displays correctly whether I install the game through TestFlight or deploy directly from Xcode.
I also have a tester who has an iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 11, and games installed from TestFlight on his device display correctly as well.
And, of course, the games display fine in all versions of the IOS simulator I’ve used for testing and debugging,

At one point I was able to have temporary access to an iPhone 6s that was having the problem. I could not find any change I could make in SpriteKit that would allow the game to display correctly. Furthermore the View Debugging feature of Xcode indicated everything was fully visible on the screen when it was clearly clipped on the device.
Also, for another user, I was able to get the game to display correctly by having them perform a factory reset of the phone in reinstalling a backup

All of this seems to indicate the problem does not lie with the code for the games, and is rather some physical problem with the phones themselves.

It is also very confusing, and I’m unclear about the cause and how to fix it.

At any rate, this does not appear to be a problem I can solve from my end of things, and I feel that I may need to reach out to Apple for help, only I’m unsure of the best way to go about this.

I don’t know if I could try logging a bug report, as I do not have clear steps on how to reproduce the problem.
I’m wondering if there is anyone I can contact through my developer account that I have that could help to troubleshoot this issue.

What suggestions do people have for dealing with this problem?

Comment: A possible issue (without any code, it's hard to judge): maybe the Zoomed Mode can play a role in this.

Comment: I wonder if you are talking about the SKCameraNode for the scene. I'm using the default camera settings, so it seems that would be consistent on all devices. Furthermore the device I did the factory reset on was an iPhone 6 with the exact same configuration as my iPhone 6. I'm unsure why the game would zoom on that iPhone and not on my iPhone. I'm wondering if you are thinking of any camera settings in particular, or are you talking about something completely different.

Comment: Or maybe you are talking about the zoom feature that is in the Accessibility settings. I enabled that and when I activate it after launching the game the scene is zoomed in much further than what is shown in the screen shot. The game is quite unplayable at that zoom setting, where as with the zoom that posted about does allow someone to actually still play the game.

Comment: I was thinking about the latter. However, if that is the case, you might want to reconsider the layout construction methods you're using. Your game should be playable with **any** setting. It's not a good idea to prevent handicapped users to play your game.

Comment: Sounds like you are not using scaleMode properly

Comment: iPhone X is not 16:9 where as iPhone 5 ~ 8+ are,  it should look broken on an iPad as well

Comment: You designed your game in a 16:9 layout, and you have `scaleMode` set to `.aspectFill`.  Since X is ~19.5:9, it is trying to scale up the 16 to 19.5, which means your 9 will scale up to 10.96875 to preserve the 16:9 ratio.  (16/9 = 19.5/10.96875).   The system has to chop of 1.96875 of the screen space to fit it properly. You need to reevaluate your game and determine what is to be expected across all aspect ratios.  Personally in your case, I would design where the main visuals fit an iPad (4:3 aka 12:9) and use the  extra space on the X and other devices as eye candy (instead of black bars)

Comment: How does this explain that one person with say an iPhone 7 Plus can install the game, and it will display properly, and someone else, with a different iPhone 7 Plus can install the game and it appears zoomed.

Comment: Also, why did a factory reset fix the problem for one phone?